# Ingress giving 502 Bad Gateway Error randomly

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

We are using nginx as the ingress controller in our cluster.

Some days back we started getting panopta bad gateway outage emails.
In the ingress logs

```
panopta-ip - [panopta-ip] - - [29/Jun/2021:10:21:02 +0000] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "http://checks.panopta.com/" "Panopta v1.1" 185 0.000 [default-webapp-8080] 100.96.12.84:8080, 100.96.12.84:8080, 100.96.12.84:8080 0, 0, 0 0.000, 0.000, 0.000 502, 502, 502 f3114b9e52a8c5d354161984458f851c
2021/06/29 10:21:04 [error] 2759#2759: *121227793 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: panopta-ip, server: my-domain.com, request: "GET /index.html HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://100.96.12.84:8080/index.html", host: "mydomain.com"
2021/06/29 10:21:09 [error] 2760#2760: *121228114 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: panopta-ip, server: mydomain.com, request: "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://100.96.12.84:8080/index.html", host: "mydomain.com", referrer: "http://checks.panopta.com/"
```

The logs were saying cant connect to pod.

When I tried to access the page in chrome it would show nginx 502 bad gateway message.
But it would automatically resolve after some time.
After searching google most links were saying it should be pod issue(as they were saying issue is related to backend)

When the issue came again we would restart the pod and it would work but issue will resurface after some time later.
So when the issue came again I checked the connectivity from other pods to webapp pod.
The other pods were able to connect through the service as well as the pod's IP.

So my question is why the ingress would have connectivity issues to the pod when the other pods were able to connect.
After checking the webapp pod and ingress pod logs, we restarted the ingress pod.
Its not giving any issues for now.

Has anyone faced similar issue.

the ingress yaml file

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
  name: web-app-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: web-app
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /mypage/
      - backend:
          serviceName: web-app
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /index.html
      - backend:
          serviceName: web-app
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /favicon.ico
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - mydomain.com
    secretName: mydomain.com-crt
```

Comment: You may be using a proxy.  In c# the proxy timeout is usually 30 seconds.  So if it is taking around 30 seconds it could be proxy.  c# will when a proxy timeout will try to connect directly with server.  does nginx resolve after 30 seconds?

Comment: The webapp is using jetty and running java webapp.
It was running fine for months
Only recently we started getting the 502 bad gateway issue.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-troubleshooting-502?force_isolation=true  Also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/428059/c-azure-function-returning-502-bad-gateway-but-no.html?force_isolation=true. Secondlink said CHUNKED (HTTP 1.1).  Maybe force to HTTP 1.0 (stream).

Comment: The mentioned errors could be caused by following reasons-

(1) In docker file, if it is set to listen to localhost or something other than 127.0.0.1
(2) The backend that is associated with our service is marked as unhealthy. In this case, the Kubernetes Ingress will not forward traffic if the backend is unhealthy, and will lead to a 502 error.
(3) Lack of properly configured network policies.

For further investigation, please share your ‘nginx.conf’ file.

Comment: The webapp is hosted in kubernetes and accessed through nginx ingress, it was working fine for more than 2 years, from last week it is giving 502 bad gateway errors